# Получить координаты курсора мыши на svg

Tags: svg, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Используем плагин https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom и svg.js.

Нужно получить координаты курсора мыши на svg. Есть решение, которое работает только в Chrome, но не работает в Firefox и ie. Знаю, что проблема с focal point при получении матрицы getScreenCTM().

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

**Обновление**

event - событие курсора

```
function getCoordinates(event){

    var svg = $("svg")[0];

    var screen = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();

    var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

    pt.x = event.clientX;

    pt.y = event.clientY;

    var point = pt.matrixTransform(screen);

    var matrix = panzoomContainer.panzoom("getMatrix");

    return {
        x: point.x * (1 / matrix[0]),
        y: point.y * (1 / matrix[3])
    };
}
```

Comment: Работает только в chrome [это решение][1]?

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/timmywil/Vu8nA/

Comment: event - событие курсора

function getCoordinates(event){

        var svg = $("svg")[0];

        var screen = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();

        var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

        pt.x = event.clientX;

        pt.y = event.clientY;
 
        var point = pt.matrixTransform(screen);        
        
        var matrix = panzoomContainer.panzoom("getMatrix");

        return {
            x: point.x * (1 / matrix[0]),
            y: point.y * (1 / matrix[3])
        };
}